# How do I retrieve row from table and fetch/open each link using urllib?

Tags: python, urllib, mysql-python

I am new to Mysqldb and Python. I manage to store all links into a table. Now I want to retrieve those links and fetch them using `urllib`. My code should save them into a Mysql table .

```
import MySQLdb
import urllib

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='shailang',
    db='urls')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open ("s.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO url(links) VALUES(%s)", line)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM url")
links = cursor.fetchall()

for row in links:
    page = urllib.urlopen(row[0])   
    text = page.read()

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your indentation is/was wrong. Have you also tried something with `urllib` you can present?

Comment: Yes here is the code : I tried. I edited my post please take a look .
By the way thanks for editing my question @colidyre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `for` loop, use `row[0]` instead of `row`.

```
for row in links:
    page = urllib.urlopen(row[0])   
    text = page.read()
```

A record in a database can have multiple values. `row` variable is a tuple (containing values of the column for the particular record) and `links` variable is a list (containing tuples which represents a record).

Since, you have only one column and you want the data of that column, we need to use `row[0]`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply , EXAMs @JRodDynamite ...i will try this .thanks

Comment: Got this error what does it means:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql1.py", line 16, in <module>
    page= urllib.urlopen(rows[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 177, in open
    fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1026, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Check the spellings of your variable name. I have used `page = urllib.urlopen(row[0])` where as you've written `page= urllib.urlopen(rows[0])`